# How to pass a variable $ _ GET in a page?

Tags: routes

I will wish to create a privileged space for some users.

I create a role 'Candidate'. I assigned permission 'access user profiles' has this role.
I create a user that uses this role. (eg, foo)

Secondly, I create a menu (see below)

```
$items['candidate/%candidate'] = array(
  'title'            => t('My candidate space'),
  'description'      => '',
  'page callback'    => 'cel_configuration_custom_page',
  'page arguments'   => array(1),
  'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

Then a linked function

```
function cel_configuration_custom_page($args){
  return 'custom';
}
```

Finally, I have emptied the cache.

When I go on the **candidate/1** page with my account **'toto'** or account **'admin'**, I have not found page.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
    $items['candidate/%user'] = array(
      'title'            => t('My candidate space'),
      'page callback'    => 'cel_configuration_custom_page',
      'page arguments'   => array(1),
      'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    );

    function cel_configuration_custom_page($account){
      return 'Custom page for ' . $account->name;
    }
```

You can't use `%candidate` as an argument for user accounts. Also, if you want to restrict access by a particular permission, don't set access callback to `TRUE` as that will grant access to everyone.

Comment: +1 for spotting the thing I wasn't spotting! `%candidate` in the menu path means Drupal will try to call `candidate_load` function, and that's probably what's causing the 404. Whereas `%user` in the menu path will try to call `user_load` function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.

To solve the problem I use as my variable in url% or ['candidate /%'] and it works properly.